# How to prevent a column from overlapping another column on window resize?

Tags: html, css

I have a two columns in a row that are separated by content with cards. When the window is shrunk or resize, the right column moves over the left column or "card" in this case. I don't want this to happen, I simply want the right column to shrink in size with the left.

I have tried changing the style of right column class to `position:fixed` or `overflow:auto`. This seems to have to not have to do with anything about position though.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card" style="display:table;">
        <h2>Events</h2>
        <table id="Events" class="dataTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
              <td>D</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style=>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Next Event</h2>
        Something about an event here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example with CSS tried:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card" style="display:table;">
        <h2>Events</h2>
        <table id="Events" class="dataTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
              <td>D</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="overflow:auto; float:right; position:fixed;">
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Next Event</h2>
        Something about an event here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect both columns/cards to shrink when I resize the window smaller, and for them not to overlap.

Comment: Can you describe what you want using pictures at various breakpoints?

Comment: I don't believe I have a high enough reputation to post pictures, but essentially when I resize the window I just want everything to shrink, not overlap.

Comment: you can post a link to something on imgur and I can inline it for you

Comment: So column B (right), should not cover column A (left).

Comment: do you have any minimum content widths?  surely the card on the right can't shrink down to a zero pixel width

Comment: Wrong: https://imgur.com/DMhD7vo , Right: https://imgur.com/JmpAAIE

Comment: @KyleMit I don't think I set any minimum content widths

Comment: Can you provide the relevant CSS that you have tried?

Comment: What is the **right** way it should look on the small screen though?

Comment: @ScottieG I've tried `<div class="column" style="overflow:auto;">`

Comment: @KyleMit It should shrink both cards, and keep them side by side. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Juan Please add the relevant CSS to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @ScottieG Added it.